# First or last value checker component/funtion

Tags: vhdl, components, component-selection, diagram

I am trying to make a circuit that can store the first and last value from a series of values. To do this I'm guessing I need a component to determine if it's the first or last value and this is what I'm struggling to find.

The data is arriving from an ADC, which is converting a spiromoteter analogue signal into digital. Each binary value of flow is inputted on a bus (with bits in parallel). My aim is to do numerical integration (Simpson's rule) for this I need to add the first and last values together.

Thank you.

Comment: Way too little information. How does the data arrive (is there a valid signal etc etc), in what format, when does the *sender* know what is the last input, what is the level of detail you need the answer to be etc.

Comment: Define first and last. Storing something is easy; retrieving it can be more problematic. A series of inputs - a plurality of inputs?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more detail about the nature of the data stream, e.g. voltage levels, timing, what separates different series of inputs, etc. before this question can be answered.

Comment: What's the protocol for the ADC datastream?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have added more detail. If you need to know anything else, let me know.

Comment: @DonFusili I don't fully understand your question. Each binary value of flow is inputted on a bus (with bits in
parallel).

Comment: It could have been an SPI protocol, for example. Is the block you are designing a master or a slave on that bus? Being a master would mean that you yourself decide what the last value is, being a slave gives you at most the option to stop listening. You should probably just post the datasheet of the ADC.

Comment: What is the point of not performing actual integration when you got an FPGA available? You will spend less logic elements on actually integrating than doing your "XY problem" solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're sure you need this, your code would probably look something like this:

```
p_main: process(clk, reset_n)

  type flowstate is (initial, gathering);
  variable r_state : flowstate;

  variable r_first_val : integer range 0 to c_max;
  variable r_second_val : integer range 0 to c_max;

begin

  if reset_n = '0' then
    r_state := initial;
    r_first_val := 0;
    r_second_val := 0;
    first_val_output_signal <= 0;
    second_val_output_signal <= 0;
  elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    -- determine if the input is valid, depends on protocol
    if inputsvalid then
      case r_state is
        when initial =>
          r_first_val := received_input;
          r_second_val := received_input;
          r_state := gathering;
        when gathering =>
          r_second_val := received_input;
          -- determine if the gathering is done, depends on protocol
          if finished_gathering then
            r_state := initial;
            -- go back to initial state
            first_val_output_signal <= r_first_val;
            second_val_output_signal <= r_second_val;
          end if;
      end case;
    end if;
  end if;

end process;
```

As you can see, much would depend on the actual protocol the data uses. You mention a bus, but not what kind of bus. Determining what data is valid and how to signal to other blocks/processes that you updated the output signals depends on your application.